# Offline documentation for Javascript/ES6, Vue, PHP, ... + a good frontend

Tags: linux, javascript, documentation

A couple of weeks ago I was working in a remote place,  with very shaky internet connectivity. I had to solve some technical problems. Some them were Javascript problems. However, it was impossible for me to go on the internet, for quickly looking things up or even doing a quick Google search.

I wished I had some searchable offline documentation brought with me. That would have been so much more convenient! I needed to lookup Object and Array methods of modern Javascript Ecmascript, for instance.

My platform is Linux, and I know there are documentation packages, e.g. `apt install coffescript-doc`. (Same for `perl-doc`, and many others). But there does not seem to be one for Javascript.

By the way, also I'd like to know which screen reader to use (besides `man` or `info`), or is there a good browser-based alternative? With better fulltext search capabilites than `man`? I'd like to have a debian package equivalent to  `perl-doc-html` ("Perl documentation suitable for viewing with a web browser") but for modern Javascript.

*If no answers appear here I'll cross post to Ask Ubuntu, or Unix&Linux*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want Zealdocs. Offline documentation for a lot of programming languages
[Zealdocs](https://zealdocs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [http://phpfui.com/InstaDoc](http://phpfui.com/?n=PHPFUI%5CInstaDoc) for this. It will fully document all your PHP source code on your local serer. Runs as a PHP script right on your website. Will produce static files if you need them for high volume sites. Easy to install and set up. Maybe 2 minutes to usable documentation for your code and all the third party code you use in your app.