# Is there software that allows for convenient offline viewing of Python3 documentation on GNU / Linux?

Tags: python, offline, documentation

Programming in C is really convenient for me on a GNU / Linux OS because documentation for all the standard library functions are at my fingertips via locally installed man pages.

Some of my current applications require Python3 programming, and sometimes I don't have access to the internet to view Python3's documentation.

Does anyone install Python3 documentation to their local machine? What is the software that you use?

Comment: I couldn't tag this as Python3, so I tagged as Python

Comment: On mobile now, check my reply here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/69800/62000

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185), [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185) or [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185).

Comment: I've rephrased the question, though it may be that the root of my question is a duplicate of the link in @Nelson comment. I went there and thumbed his answer. It solved my problem almost perfectly. I'd prefer something I could launch from the command line and view in a terminal window like with man pages, but this gets the job done